# Cut list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

Given a limit and a list of lists containing an arbitrary number of items, i would like to cut the list of lists where the limit is the total number of items from all lists.

My effort so far:

```
lol = [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s', '0', 'u', 'x']]

def cut_lol(lol, n):
    count = 0
    result = []
    for l in lol:
        if count + len(l) > (n):
            new_len_l = count + len(l) - n
            result.append(l[:new_len_l])
            return result
        result.append(l)
        count += len(l)
    return result
```

But something is wrong with this function and i can't see what.

For example:

```
print(cut_lol(lol, 8))
# returns    [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s', '0', 'u']]
# should be: [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s']]


print(cut_lol(lol, 4))
# returns    [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b']]
# should be: [['a', 'v', '1', 'r']]


print(cut_lol(lol, 3))
# returns    [['a']]
# should be: [['a', 'v', '1']]
```

Can anyone help me make this work? Thanks!

Comment: And it should not return empty lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a `for` loop and a conditional return:

```
def cut_lol(lol, n):
    result = []
    for li in lol:
        if n <= 0:
            return result
        sli = li[:n]
        result.append(sli)
        n -= len(sli)
    return result
```

So here we iterate over the sublists `li` in `lol`. Each time we check if the remaining number of elements `n` has already reached zero, in which case we return the thus far obtained result. Otherwise we append a sliced version of the sublist such that it contains at most `n` elements. We each time decrement the number.

We can improve the efficiency by making the slicing conditional:

```
def cut_lol(lol, n):
    result = []
    for li in lol:
        if n <= 0:
            return result
        sli = li
        if len(sli) > n:
            sli = sli[:n]
        result.append(sli)
        n -= len(sli)
    return result
```

**Sample output**:

```
>>> cut_lol(lol, 0)
[]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 1)
[['a']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 2)
[['a', 'v']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 3)
[['a', 'v', '1']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 4)
[['a', 'v', '1', 'r']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 5)
[['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 6)
[['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 7)
[['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b']]
>>> cut_lol(lol, 8)
[['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s']]
```

This will also work with tuples, and other sliceable objects (in which case the result will be a list of these sliced objects).

Comment: Thanks! I chose your answer because it elegantly uitilizes python list slicing using negative values as well as keeping performance in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Minimal changes to make it work:

```
lol = [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s', '0', 'u', 'x']]

def cut_lol(lol, n):
    count = 0
    result = []
    for l in lol:
        if count + len(l) > (n):
            new_len_l = n - count
            if new_len_l:
                result.append(l[:new_len_l])
            return result
        result.append(l)
        count += len(l)
    return result
```

Simplified version:

```
lol = [['a', 'v', '1', 'r'], ['d', 'x', 'b'], ['s', '0', 'u', 'x']]

def cut_lol(lol, n):
    count = 0
    result = []
    for l in lol:
        to_read = n - count
        if to_read <= 0:
            break
        result.append(l[:to_read])
        count += len(l)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!